# Which one is a better option - web3js or golang apis?

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, dapps, external-api

I want to build an application where I can call methods from smart contracts. I can do so by using either [web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/) or golang apis.

**Query:**
Which one is a better option when interacting with smart contracts and why?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve all these things with pretty much either of the two and it depends what do you want to build and what your background is.

If you are building a web app, and have been using JavaScript (or are willing to), then you just have the best and richest library to interact with an ethereum node. You have a mature **community**, **enough documentations**, and entry level **tutorials** all around the web.

If you have to/ love to use Go, then you may do so as one of main ethereum clients [geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth) itself is written in Go.

A right comparison would be [web3j](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/) or [web3py](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), etc. as these are more of high-level libraries that implement the functionalities that the nodes run.